# How to access the front matter in a docusaurus website?

Tags: plugins, docusaurus, yaml-front-matter

I am working on a docusaurus based website which has front matter available in the following format.

```
---
id: introduction
title: Welcome to Rowy
slug: /
---
```

I am integrating [Cusdis](https://cusdis.com/) (an open source commment system plugin) and I wish to consume the page id and title front matter. How can I do that?

I tried using a variety of methods to consume the front matter, for example `{props. }` for the following code.

```html
<head>
  <script async defer src="https://cusdis.com/js/cusdis.es.js"></script>
</head>

<div id="cusdis"
  data-host="https://cusdis.com"
  data-app-id="**********************************"
  data-page-id= {props.id}
  data-page-url="http://docs.rowy.io"
  data-page-title= {props.title}
  data-theme="auto"
></div>
```

Here, `{props.id}` is being read as the **Introduction** which is the value of `{props.id}`, which is weird. Would love some guidance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Frontmatter can be accessed via the following within a Markdown page, so I'm assuming it could work in your plugin.

```
<div>
{frontMatter.fieldname}
</div>
```